# Algorithm to traverse a grid collecting as many points as possible

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-algorithm, discrete-mathematics, dna-sequence

Consider a 2-dimensional m*n grid where each cell can contain either a 1 or a 0. Find the greatest value a traversal can acquire by moving through this grid. The value can be increased by traversing diagonally through a 1 cell. A traversal of the grid obeys the following rules:

1. Start at the top-left cell.
2. At each cell the traversal may move down one grid, move right one grid, or move diagonally (move down one grid and move right one grid). If the cell contains a 1 and the traversal moves diagonally then the traversal value increases by 1.
3. The traversal cannot move off the grid (if at the right edge cannot move right, if at the bottom edge cannot move down).
4. End at the lower right corner.

A naive algorithm would consider all 3*m*n traversals and pick the largest value. Can someone help me come up with a better solution? Is there an algorithm that solves a similar problem?

This isn't an interview question, I need this to try to optimize the Smith-Waterman algorithm.

#### Examples:

The following grid has a maximum value of 2:

[image]

This one has a maximum value of 7:

[image]

Comment: Here are some examples. The following grid has a maximum value of 2 http://imgur.com/bT3ROru

This grid has a maximum value of 7. http://imgur.com/55jU5XJ

Comment: Pretty sure you need Dynamic Programming. Let `f(x,y)` be the maximum value of a path that ends at cell `(x,y)`. It can be computed from the values `f(x-1,y)`, `f(x,y-1)` and `f(x,y)`, so it can be solved in `O(n*m)` which seems optimal seeing as that is the size of the input.

Comment: Need you to clarify the question a bit more because the criteria to collect a point seems vague to me. Suppose you move from cell [x,y] to [x+1,y+1] (diagonal movement), and also suppose the step prior to this and after this are neither diagonal, does a value 1 in cell [x,y] qualify you to collect 1 point, or does a value 1 in cell [x+1,y+1] qualify you to collect 1 point?

Answer (score 3):

Use dynamic programming:

```
dp[i, j] = maximum value obtainable from [1, 1] to [i, j]
dp[1, _] = dp[_, 1] = 0 -> we cannot get to any of these diagonally
dp[i, j] = max(dp[i - 1, j], -> come from above
i, j > 1       dp[i, j - 1], -> come from the left
               dp[i - 1, j - 1] + v[i, j] -> come diagonally and add what is at [i, j]
              )
```

The answer will be in `dp[m, n]`.

The complexity is `O(n*m)`, which is optimal since it takes this much just to read the input.

**Note:**

> A naive algorithm would consider all 3*m*n traversals and pick the largest value

This should actually be `3 to the power of (n*m)`, because for each cell, you'd have 3 possibilities if you brute forced it.

Comment: I feel like this algorithm is not fundamentally different from Smith-Waterman. What I'm trying to do is make the algorithm highly parallel and this approach reintroduces strong data dependency between cells.

Comment: His "naive algorithm" means the Smith-Waterman algorithm, which is also O(n*m). [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm)

Comment: That is not at all deducible from your question. You should edit your question and say that you are interested in ways to make the algorithm parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can transformed into a graph problem where vertices represent your cells, and edges represent possible connection between adjacent cells or diagonal adjacent cells.

all you edges have weight 0, except the ones represent a diagonal travel starting from a 1 cell.

You have now transformed your problem into a longest path problem on a directed acyclic graph(DAG). This is equivalent of solving a shortest path problem on an DAG with negative equivalent weights (i.e. all edges with weight 1 turn to weight -1)

For shortest path in a DAG with negative weight, use Bellman-Ford algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to recursively branch traveling on the diagonal and intelligently pruning for only the highest values, but this approach is too convoluted.

I asked this question for a parallelizable Smith-Waterman algorithm and in the end I'm going to use this http://biochem218.stanford.edu/Projects%202002/Byang.pdf